# Kazhdan-Lusztig basis elements appearing in product with distinguished involution

Tags: coxeter-groups, hecke-algebras, weyl-group, affine-hecke-algebras

My apologies if the below is too malformed to make sense.

Let $(W,S)$ be the affine Weyl group of a reductive group $G$, and let $\{C_w\}$ be the Kazhdan-Lusztig $C$-basis (an answer in terms of the $C'_w$-basis is of course equally useful, though). Let $H$ be the corresponding Hecke algebra over $\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$, and write $h_{x,y,z}$ for the structure constants of $H$ in the $C_w$-basis.

It is know that $W$ is partitioned into finitely-many two-sided cells, and finitely-many left cells, each of which contains a distinguished involution $d$ (all these terms understood in the sense of Kazhdan-Lusztig and Lusztig). Let $w\in W$ and let $\Gamma$ be the left cell containing $w$. Let $d$ be the distinguished involution in $\Gamma$.

Consider the structure constants $h_{w,d,z}$ for $z\in\Gamma$. What is known about them? For example, is it known in general for which $z$ they are nonzero?

For example, in the case when $d=s$ is a simple reflection, we have
$$
C_wC_s=-(q^{1/2}+q^{-1/2})C_w,
$$
so that $h_{w,d,w}=-(q^{1/2}+q^{-1/2})$ and $h_{w,d,z}=0$ otherwise.

In the other extreme, let $W_0\subset W$ be the finite Weyl group, with longest element $w_0$. Then the lowest two-sided cell contains $W_0$-many distinguished involutions, all conjugate to $w_0$. In this case for $w$ in the same left cell as $w_0$, $C_wC_{w_0}$ is again proportional to $C_w$, and $h_{w,w_0,w}$ is itself proportional to the number of $\mathbb{F}_q$-points of the finite-dimensional flag variety of $G$.

It seems too much to hope for that $C_wC_d$ will always be proportional to $C_w$, but perhaps something like this is almost true?

Comment: Indeed even $C_dC_d$ is not always proporitional to $C_d$. In type $\tilde{B}_3$, this happens for the distinguished involution $d=s_2s_0s_1s_3s_2$, one has $h_{d,d,w}=-(v+v^{-1})$ for $w=s_2s_3s_1s_0s_2s_3s_1s_0s_2$. It can be checked that $w$ and $d$ are even in the same left cell.